# Re-write regex expression number filtering Python

Tags: python, regex, string, filter, expression

Given a string like 'hello 0796XXXXXX. TODAY IS UR LUCKY DAY£500 Cash', I use the following regex

`re.findall(r"(\b07\d*|\b08\d*|\b09\d*)", t)` to receive the numbers that start with 07 | 08 | 09 and are followed by 0 or more digits. `['0796']` is the result.

How do I have to re-write the code so that `\b` and `\d*` are not repeated? I tried `re.findall(r"\b(07|08|09)\d*)", t)` e.g., but unfortunately it does not work and only returns `[07]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the parentheses, and put the 0 aside that is also repeated:

```
re.findall(r"\b0[789]\d*", t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = r"(07|08|09)\d*"
re.findall(regex, text)
```